# Can I add comma or leave it as per my preference?

Tags: american-english, punctuation

In the participle clause describing "an action that happens at the same time with another action in the past", like "moth swings the wings emerging from the chrysalis", can I add a comma after "wings"? Cause every time I see the random article. Some people add the comma, but some leave it out.

Comment: The comma is optional: the word "while" is implied in its place.

Answer (score 1):

A moth swings its wings emerging from  chrysalis.

You don't need to put a comma after wings.

However, if you start the sentence with a participial phrase, you need to put a comma after the phrase as follows:

Emerging from  chrysalis, a moth swings its wings.